# Linux Permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems

I am new to Linux. I am trying to copy some files from one folder on a Linux server to another folder on the same folder. The folders have different owners; however, I have read and write permissions on both folders. I used the command

```
chmod 777 /tmp/source_data
```

and then I tried the command

```
cp -r /tmp/source_data /projects/project_1
```

However, I got the error "file or directory not found".  Can someone please give me some advise?

Comment: What are the permissions on /projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the /projects/project_1 directory doesn't exist judging by the error. Either that, or you're in the wrong directory, you might need to use the full path.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because the folder `/projects/project_1` doesn't exist, you will need to create it like so:

```
mkdir /projects/project_1
```

And then do the `cp` command:

```
cp -r /tmp/source_data /projects/project_1
```